# Series of non negative terms diverges then does $\frac{\sum a_i^2}{(\sum a_i)^2} \to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Suppose $\{a_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of nonnegative numbers such that $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \to \infty$. Suppose that there exist a distribution function $F$ (non decreasing, right continuous, $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to-\infty} F(x)=0$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} F(x)=1$) with $F(0)=0$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{I}_{(a_i \le x)}=F(x)$$ 
>   Then is it true that
>   $$\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i^2}{\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2} \to 0 \ \ ?$$

My try:

Note that without the distribution condition the above limit is not true. Just take $a_n$ such that it dominates $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{n-1}$ for example we can take $a_n=n^{2n}$. Then $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{n-1}= \mathcal{O}(n^{2n-1})$ and the limit goes to 1.

Suppose we define $x_{n}^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i^2$ and $y_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i$. and let $z_n^2=\frac{x_n^2}{y_n^2}$. Then
$$\begin{aligned} z_{n+1}^2 & =\frac{x_{n}^2+a_{n+1}^2}{(y_n+a_{n+1})^2} \\ & = \frac{z_n^2+t_n^2}{(1+t_n)^2}\end{aligned}$$
where $t_n:= \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}$.

I am stuck here. Any help/suggestions?

Comment: Try to express $\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^2$ as Riemann Stieltjes integrals wrt. $\sum_{j \le n} \mathbb{I}_{a_i \le x}$.  Then look at the quotient again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is false.
You can try the sequence:

1,1,

1,2^2

1,1,1,3^3

1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4^4

and so on.

Basically the idea is to fuse the sequence you use with the constant 1 in a way such that the measure is a delta in 1 but the structure of the sequence has the dominance you suppose.

Note also that F(0)=0 implies that the series of a_n diverges making that condition redundant.